# Limit the number of emails sent by meteor app?

Tags: email, meteor

Can someone explain me how to limit the number of sent emails from meteor app? I want to prevent my app from spammers.

This is my code:

/server/email.js file:

```
Meteor.methods({

 sendEmail: function (text) {
  check([text], [String]);
   this.unblock();
   Email.send({
    to: 'x@y.com',
    from: 'y@z.com',
    subject: 'New message from contact form',
    text: text,
   });
  }
});
```

/client/contact.js file:

```
Template.contactForm.events({
  'submit form#contactForm':function(e){
    var contactForm = $(e.currentTarget),
     fname = contactForm.find('#firstName').val(),
     email = contactForm.find('#email').val(),
     message = contactForm.find("#message").val();

     var dataText = "Message from: " + 
                  fname + " " + 
                  "\rEmail: " + email + 
                  "\rContent:" + message;

      Meteor.call('sendEmail', dataText);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Can you please give more details and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lack details, but I assume that you are looking for a validation that the user is not a bot, and will not abuse your `sendMail` method.

You can use goggle reCAPTCHA with [this package](https://github.com/Altapp/Meteor-reCAPTCHA) once you will have your setup keys and settings [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)